# How can I add a UIView behind the main UIView for a slide out menu in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to make a basic slide out menu without the use of an API to practice with animation and overlaying views within the superview. I also despise the interface builder, so I'm looking for a 100% programmatic solution.

I've created a basic view with a navigation bar, and I want the main view to slide right revealing a TableViewController. I have this function that I'm using to slide the main view to the right, but all I get is a black screen where the TableViewController should be.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand : Bool){

    let frameWidth = self.view.frame.width;
    let frameHeight = self.view.frame.height;
    slideOutMenu.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight);

    if (shouldExpand) {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {() in

            self.view.addSubview(self.slideOutMenu.tableView);
            self.view.sendSubviewToBack(self.slideOutMenu.tableView)
            self.view.center.x += frameWidth - 50;
            self.menuShouldSlide = false;

        })

    } else {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {() in

            self.slideOutMenu.tableView.removeFromSuperview();
            self.view.center.x -= frameWidth - 50.0;
            self.menuShouldSlide = true;
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the tableView on top of the main view which means that it will move with the main view and leave the back empty.

```
self.view.addSubview(self.slideOutMenu.tableView)
```

What you need to do is add another view on self.view above the `slideOutMenu.tableView`and use that as the content view.

Comment: Ok, awesome. Give me a few minutes to try to implement this and if I can get it working I will mark this as correct.

Comment: So I'm probably missing something obvious, but I've tried to create an additional view, add the table view to that, and then add that new view as a subview of self.view and I'm getting the same effect. Is this the general process you were prescribing?

Comment: The animation needs to happen on the content view not self.view